# Python Regex: Match a string not preceded by or followed by a word with digits in it

Tags: python, regex

I would like to have a Regex in Python to replace a string not preceded by or followed by a word with digits in it.

i.e.

For the following sentence,

Today is 4th April. Her name is **April**. Tomorrow is April 5th.

I would like to match the April(in bold) only and replace it with 'PERSON' and result should be like below:

Today is 4th April. Her name is **PERSON**. Tomorrow is April 5th.

I tried to use this regex:

```
(\w*(?<!\w*\d\w*\s)April(?!\s\w*\d\w*))
```

However, I've got an error saying:

```
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is done by matching and capturing, `\w*?\d\w*\s+April|(April)(?!\s+\w*?\d)`

Comment: What about punctuation? Would you want to match "5th. April" since the previous word was at the end of a sentence?

Comment: It should match '5th, April' as you said there is punctuation in between.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with [Pypi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that supports variable-length lookbehind.

```
import regex

str = 'Today is 4th April. Her name is April. Tomorrow is April 5th.'
res = regex.sub(r'(?<!\d[a-z]* )April(?! [a-z]*\d)', 'PERSON', str)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
Today is 4th April. Her name is PERSON. Tomorrow is April 5th.
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\d[a-z]* )      # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't a digit followed by 0 or more letters and a space before
April               # literally
(?! [a-z]*\d)       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a space, 0 or more letters and a digit after
```

---

**Update with `re` module:**

```
import re

str = 'Today is 4th April. Her name is April. Tomorrow is April 5th.'
res = re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+ )April(?! [a-z]*\d)', '\g<1>PERSON', str)
print(res)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the permission to install new packages. re is all I have to work with.

Comment: @Allen: See my update, it works with standard `re` module

Answer (score 1):

This is one regex you could use:

```
(?:^\s+|[^\w\s]+\s*|\b[^\d\s]+\s+)(April)\b(?!\s*\w*\d)
```

with the case-indifferent flag set. The target word is captured in capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/56GcUs/7/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations:

```
(?:           # begin non-cap grp
  ^           # match beginning of line
  \s*         # match 0+ whitespace characters
  |           # or
  [^\w\s]+    # match 1+ chars other than word chars and whitespace
  \s*         # match 0+ whitespace chars
  |           # or
  \b          # match word break
  [^\d\s]+    # match 1+ chars other than digits and whitespace
  \s+         # match 1+ whitespace chars
)             # end non-cap grp  
(April)       # match 'April' in capture group
\b            # match word break
(?!           # begin negative lookahead
  \s*         # match 0+ whitespace chars         
  \w*         # match 0+ word chars
  \d          # match a digit
)             # end negative lookahead
```

The approach I've taken was to specify what may precede `"April"` and why may not follow it. I could not specify what cannot precede `"April"` as that would require a negative lookbehind, which is not supported by Python's regex engine.

I've assume that `"April"` may:

- be at the beginning of the string, possibly followed by spaces;
- be preceded by a character that is neither a word character nor a space, possibly followed by spaces; or
- be preceded by a word containing no digits, possibly followed by spaces.

I've also assumed that `"April"` is followed by a word break which may not be followed by a word containing a digit, possibly preceded by spaces.

Comment: That's amazing! It worked! Would you mind explaining it a bit? I want to pull my hair at the moment :-)

Comment: Thanks @Cary, I found one little problem. It seems this regex also captures the word preceeding April. For example: ''Her name is April.' would become ''Her name PERSON.' when I tried to repace it using re.sub. Note the word 'is' is also captured and replaced.

Comment: In `"Her name is April"` the match is `"is April"`, whereas the content of capture group 1 is `"April"`. It's the latter you need to replace. I don't believe it's possible to match just `"April"` with Python's regex engine and your requirements, but that should not be a problem.